# JAXB - custom annotation with value from xsd

Tags: jaxb, xsd, annotations

I have case where I'm trying to generate java-classes from a lot of different xsd's.
Every simpleType, complextype, element has additional properties other than name and type that I would like JAXB to represent in my java-classes.

Examples (snippet of XSD):

```
    <xsd:complexType name="InternInformasjon" seres:elementtype="Meldingsdel"
                     seres:guid="http://seres.no/guid/StatistiskSentralbyrå/Meldingsdel/InternInformasjon/479039">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="periodeFritekst" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"
                       seres:guid="http://seres.no/guid/StatistiskSentralbyrå/Dataegenskap/periode/479038"
                       seres:elementtype="Dataegenskap" type="Tekst_50"/>
.......
```

Is there any way I can make JAXB obtain the string after "seres:guid" on these fields and annotate them in my classes? Or make this info available runtime unmarshalling some other way? That URL is an unique identifier of that element/field and will be used later in the application.

As I said i have a lot of large xsd's I would like to generate classes for, so any manual modification is not wanted.

```
The resulting class should look something like this:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InternInformasjon", propOrder = {
"periodeFritekst",
/* Ommitted */
})
@Guid("http://seres.no/guid/StatistiskSentralbyrå/Meldingsdel/InternInformasjon/479039")
public class InternInformasjon {
    @XmlElementRef(guid="http://seres.no/guid/StatistiskSentralbyrå/Dataegenskap/periode/479038", name = "periodeFritekst", namespace = "http://seres.no/xsd/StatistiskSentralbyrå/2013", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> periodeFritekst;
    /* Ommitted */
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: The only way I can see how this could be achieved is by a JAXB plugin for xjc, the XML Schema compiler. - But providing this info as annotations may not be the only way. After rxtracting the info from the XML Schemas (using XSLT), it could be made accessible to the application as an external data structure.

Comment: Yep, probably the only way is a custom XJC plugin. Take a look at my annotate plugin. It can annotate the resulting classes, but it won't process your `seres:guid`: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin